# What does it mean? expr1 = expr2 Mod expr3 = 0

Tags: php, vba, modulo, ternary

So I am porting a VBA application to PHP and ran into this wonderful little nugget of code:

```
expr1 = expr2 Mod expr3 = 0
```

I thought it was behaving like a ternary operator but when I broke it down to simple if then statements the outcome was not as expected. So I ask the brilliant stack**overflow** community to help me out and put it in easy to understand terms. I know by looking at the other answers I will not be let down. [/end brown_nose>]

Comment: Bad bad code :)
Looking at expression, my mind right away assume that this is a comparision in an if / while, etc. statement.  Combined that with lack of grouping and VB assigment = comparison operator and dynamic type conversion, hehe.  If you are not familiar w/ operator precedence, it's very easy to read that as (expr1 == expr2) % (expr3 == 0)... which can easily result in Divide By Zero.  Very bad :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the modulus operator:

```
a MOD b = remainder of a/b
```

in PHP it is the % sign:

```
a%b
```

[see php documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

So the line

```
expr1 = expr2 Mod expr3 = 0
```

means: expr1 is true, if expr2 can be divided by expr3 without any remainders:
eg:

```
20 MOD 5 = 0 ==> TRUE
22 MOD 5 = 2 ==> FALSE
```

Comment: but what is the = 0 on the end used for?

Comment: Wow tough to assign the answer to, I choose Peter since he wrote back with a better explanation (even though while it was coming in I was asking Jacob almost the same thing. You both rock. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

It's assigning expr1 to a boolean value that indicates whether expr2 can be divided evenly (with no remainder) by expr3.  Remember that = means == in VB :D.

Here's what it would look like with the implied parentheses:

```
expr1 = ((expr2 Mod expr3) = 0)
```

Comment: Why would the = operator right-associate? I would sort of expect that `a = b = c` associates as `(a = b) = c`.

Comment: So is it correct to think like this:
Using your example if:
expr2 = 2
expr3 = 4
expr1 would be true (1)?

Comment: Maybe my wording was backwards, but no.  The remainder of 2 / 4 is 2, so that would evaluate to False.  But if expr2 is 4 and expr3 is 2, then it would evaluate to True.

Comment: Actually, I think I was backwards. Thanks!